# Does this example contradict Earnshaw's theorem in one dimension?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, potential-energy, classical-electrodynamics, equilibrium

This is basically a continuation of the post [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/470522/facing-a-paradox-ehrenfest-theorem-in-one-dimension/470523?noredirect=1#comment1057819_470523).

Consider electrostatics in $1$-dimension (say, the $x$-axis). Now consider a positive charge $+q$ located at $x=0$, and two equal negative charges $-q$ are held fixed at $x=+a$ and $x=-a$. In this configuration, the total force on $+q$ at $x=0$ is zero i.e., the charge at $x=0$ is in equilibrium. Moreover, it is also a stable equilibrium i.e., if we slightly displace $q$ towards left or right, then it would oscillate about $x=0$. This means that it is possible to keep the charge $+q$ in stable equilibrium by electrostatic forces alone.

But this again goes against Earnshaw's theorem. Again I must be missing something. Is it that when I say the charges at $x=\pm a$ are held fixed, I am using mechanical forces and thus move outside the purview of Earnshaw's theorem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Earnshaw's theorem indeed holds in any number of spatial dimensions. The problem here is your assumption about the electric field.

In any number of dimensions, the electric field obeys Gauss's law. So in $d$ spatial dimensions,
$$E(r) \propto \frac{1}{r^{d-1}}.$$
In particular, for $d = 1$, the electric field of a charge is constant. This makes sense, because the field lines don't have any direction to "spread out" in. In your setup, the electric field due to the negative charges is exactly zero everywhere between them, so the equilibrium is only neutrally stable, in accordance with Earnshaw's theorem.

Comment: Aha! Wonderful and insightful answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I might have held the charges at $x=\pm a$ by using mechanical forces, only electrical forces apply on the charge at $x=0$. So I'm still allowed to apply Earnshaw's theorem. Is that correct to contemplate? @knzhou

Comment: @SRS Yes, you're allowed to hold some things fixed, and then only talk about the stability of the other things. Stability is a local notion. Holding certain charges fixed is really just like saying you postulate certain boundary conditions for the electric field on $(-a, a)$.

Comment: Of course it is quite speculative what electrodynamics would look like in other dimensions. I agree, though that if you consider Gauss law as fundamental then your E field would be right.

Comment: @lalala Yes, I skipped to Gauss's law to keep the answer short. The usual way E&M in arbitrary dimensions is specified is by the covariant form, $F = dA$ and $d \star F = 0$. If we define $E^i = F^{i0}$, then $d \star F = 0$ gives Gauss's law in all dimensions.

Comment: To be precise, this should say "the electric field *due to the two negative charges* is exactly zero everywhere between the two charges". And of course this is the field that matters for the force on the positive charge. But the total (actual) electric field, including that of the positive charge, is different.